# I cant set sigleEvents flag on the google calendar api request

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

Im implementing a calendar on my project using the google api to retrieve data and then render it into my js plugin, and it works fin but with the recurrent events. im trying to set the singleEvents flag en my request to retrieve the recurrent event instances instead the recurrent event itself, but is not working.

my code:

```
foreach($cals as $cal){
                $optParam = array(
                    'singleEvents' => TRUE
                );
                $events = $service->events->listEvents($cal->id, $optParam);
                while(true) {
                    $eventArray = array();
                    foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
                        if($event->getStatus != 'cancelled'){
                            {RETRIEVE DATA}
                        }
                    }
                    $pageToken = $events->getNextPageToken();
                    if ($pageToken) {
                        $optParams = array(
                            'pageToken' => $pageToken
                        );
                        $events = $service->events->listEvents($cal->id, $optParams);
                    } else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Any suggestions will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set the '*singleEvents*' flag to true when calling the '*Events:list*'

Based on the Official Google Documentation, whether to expand recurring events into instances and only return single one-off events and instances of recurring events but not underlying recurring events themselves. The default is False.

For your reference, click here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list